# where to put checking edittext syntax?

Tags: android, android-edittext

i need a favor.. i'm confused to put these codes to check whether the edittext is empty or not:

```
String input = editText.getText().toString();

if(input == null || input.trim().equals("")){
  Toast.makeText(context, "Sorry you did't type anything"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

where must i write these codes? is it between these codes?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menuawal);
...
...
...

JmlAhliWarisAnakLK = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.JmlAhliWarisAnakLK);
JmlAhliWarisAnakPR = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.JmlAhliWarisAnakPR);
```

or in this function after double sisa=0;??

```
public void cc() {

    int JmlWarisAnakPR = Integer.parseInt(JmlAhliWarisAnakPR.getText().toString());
    int JmlWarisAnakLK = Integer.parseInt(JmlAhliWarisAnakLK.getText().toString());
    int JmlHarta = Integer.parseInt(JmlHartaPeninggalan.getText().toString());
    double HasilSuami = 0;
    double HasilIstri = 0;
    double HasilAnakLK = 0;
    double HasilAnakPR = 0;
    double sisa = 0;



    }
```

please correct me if i'm wrong.. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are on the right track

After you set the layout using `setContentView` you need to add your `EditText`'s which you are doing fine as follows.

```
 JmlAhliWarisAnakLK = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.JmlAhliWarisAnakLK);
 JmlAhliWarisAnakPR = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.JmlAhliWarisAnakPR);
```

You then need to store the value you get from the `EditText`'s in some variable,

```
int JmlWarisAnakPR = Integer.parseInt(JmlAhliWarisAnakPR.getText().toString());
  ....
    ....
```

After you have stored your values you can then call some method that validates your input on click of a button(if you have):

```
public void validateinput()
{
    if(input == null || input.trim().equals(""))
  {
     Toast.makeText(context, "Sorry you did't type anything"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me, you should put the check on some event, like if its login screen, then on click of submit button. or other wise on focus change it main instantly provide user with the toast that he left the field empty. or if other case, please provide more information for your query. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on when you want to validate the editText..You propably have some button which "submits" the `EditText` so call this code in after onClick event gets fired on the button..

Answer (score 0):

Put the input validation code when you have to navigate away from the current activity, either to go to another activity or to save the input details. That's the least annoying place to shove an error message onto the user.

Another approach is to validate when the focus leaves the EditText. But in this case the error notification should be more subtle (and therefore less annoying) like changing the EditText's background to lightred.

Answer (score 0):

Ur questions does not seem to be clear. Are u asking where do u need to put the validation for empty edittext? If this is ur question then the general case would be to validate during any events such as BUTTON CLICK. Set the onClickListener for ur button and inside ur onclick perform the validation.

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = editText.getText().toString();

if(input == null || input.trim().equals("")){
  Toast.makeText(context, "Sorry you did't type anything"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Your above code is pretty much correct. You Must need to add above code whenever you want to take input from these edittext, Or whenever you want to save these value. make a function which will return true if edit text is empty so u can ask user to enter values

```
public boolean isETEmpty(){
String input = editText.getText().toString();

if(input == null || input.trim().equals("")){
  Toast.makeText(context, "Sorry you did't type anything"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 return true;    
}

   return false; // if not empty

 }
```

call this function Whenever u want to use values from ET, if this function return true, you must let user enter values. Such as on Button Click to save etc